# A possible loop to rename files in order from a directory?

Tags: python, for-loop, rename

I have a 100 .fits files in a directory with long names (ex. spec-0355-51788-0484.fits       spec-0493-51957-0157.fits, spec-0367-51997-0430.fits, spec-0771-52370-0017.fits etc...)

I am wondering if there is a loop to rename them all in a sequence of integers so that it looks like 1.fits, 2.fits, 3.fits, 4.fits, .... 100.fits

Comment: What have you done to try this, fetching a list of files in a directory is straightforward in Python, loops are standard, and renaming a file isn't difficult either.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
import os
import glob
os.chdir("E:/")
i = 1
for old_file in glob.glob("*.fits"): 
    new = str(i) + ".fits"
    os.renames(old_file, new)
    i=i+1
```

Comment: @user1821176 you should change 'E:/' to the directory where your files are

Comment: is .txt suppose to be .fits?

Comment: Nice answer, only that `file`may cause name collision with the `file` function.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend trying this.
This will rename the files by adding an index before the name of the file.

Example:

How to install.fits, Hello world tutorial.fits, .......

would rename to

1 How to install.fits, 2 Hello world tutorial.fits, ......

```
import os

path = 'C:/Users/username/Desktop/My files' #path of folder containing files you want to rename
i = 1
for filename in os.listdir(path):
    os.rename(os.path.join(path,filename), os.path.join(path, str(i)+ " " + filename + '.fits'))
    i = i + 1
```

If you don't like to put the original file name at all then simply remove adding filename in os.path.join

```
os.path.join(path, str(i)+ " " + '.fits')) #for not including original file name
```